# MariaDb / Mysql Rank function- One partition ranked before the other

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.4

I have two rank functions and one works as expected. However, the other one ranks one partition before the other partitions. Here's the code:

```
 if(count1>=3 and count2>=2 and count3>=2,
rank() over (partition by examdateID, sClass Order By orderColumn desc), count(StudentID) over (partition by examdateID, sClass)) as ClassRank ,     


if(count1>=3 and count2>=2 and count3>=2,
 rank() over (partition by examDateID, sClass, stream Order By orderColumn desc), count(StudentID) over (partition by examdateID, sClass, stream )) as StreamRank from...
```

I have two streams and I expect the classRank will give a rank of all students across the streams. However all in stream 1 are ranked before stream 2 ...3.. etc

if the condition (count1,2,3) is not met, I just expect the total number of students

could you point me in the right direction?

I'm using MariaDb 10.4.10

Edit::
I've realized that the problem is the if... when I remove it, ranking is ok
Maybe rank() can't be put inside if... still need suggestions

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)